# Login slider with jQuery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, animation, slider

I want to make a login slider with jQuery. You will have a div at the top of your page with a plus image. I want the plus image to be changed into a minus image and the div will slide down. Here is my code but there is a problem.

```
<script src="_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").hide();

    $(".open").click(function() {
        $("form").slideDown("slow");
        $(".open").addClass("close");
        $(".close").removeClass("open");

        $(".close").click(function() {
        $("form").slideUp("slow");
        $(".close").addClass("open");
        $(".open").removeClass("close");
    }); 

});


});



</script>
```

It works once but if you want to slide it down for the second theme it doesn't work anymore.. Can somebody help my please?

tnx!

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2U9n/2/)

Try something different like the following:

```
 $('.open').click(function () {
     $('form').slideToggle('slow', function () {
         $('.open').toggleClass('form-is-open');
     });
 });
```

jQuery offers some toggle functions which supply the desired behaviour. This way you don't need two click handlers or keep track of classes yourself. The above code simply adds a class ('form-is-open') to the button, when the form is shown and removes it, when it is hidden.